# Can the pattern of these series be revealed?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, permutations, combinations

I have encountered with these numbers while doing some mathematical induction and I am trying to reveal the function that contains binomials behind this. I have these series on $k$,$j$ and $i$ as following.

$k=1$ :

$$j=1:\;\{2,1\},\quad j=2:\;\{1,1\}$$

$k=2$ :

$$j=1:\;\{6,6,1\},\quad j=2:\;\{4,6,2\},\quad j=3:\; \{1,2,1\}$$

$k=3$ :

$$j=1:\; \{20,30,12,1\},\quad  
 j=2:\; \{15,30,18,3\},\quad j=3:\; \{6,15,12,3\},\quad j=4:\; \{1,3,3,1\}$$

Any observations on these series!

The first observation:

The left most for each $k$ is $\binom{k}{i-1} \binom{2k-i+1}{k}$ and the right most is nothing but $\binom{k}{i-1}$. Now I think we should employ $j$, so if we substitute $j=1$, the left most appears and if we substitute $j=k+1$, the right most appears.

Comment: The rightmost entries in each row are binomial coefficients. Can you say more about the context these numbers arose from? What is your exact goal: a polynomial in the variables $i,j,k$ that gives the answer? What are the values of $i$ exactly?

Comment: Yes. These numbers arise from doing an integral containing many parameters and this pattern is the same for one of the parameters. My goal is to have a function that represent the sequence in the variables $i,j,k$. The value of i is {1,2...k+1} for each k.

Comment: Can I buy a vowel?  Please show the "integral containing many parameters" and indicate which parameter pertains to this pattern.  Also, mathSE reviewers are going to ask you to *show work* before giving you an answer - what have you tried?

Comment: Yes. The right most is the binomial cofficients "k c (i-1)"  for j=k+1. I think there is q unique expression containing combination that represent the whole sequence.

Comment: The leftmost entries are A104684: http://oeis.org/A104684

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes. Thanks a lot! We now get the left and right most. We still have to reveal the pattern.

Comment: @user2661923  Thank you. The question is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern has been revealed.
The sequences can be represent as a expression as :

$\binom{k}{i-1} \binom{2k-i+1}{k-j+1}$

This is representation is valid for all $k$ and $j$.

Thanks for all of you have given observations.

Comment: @AndyWalls , can you please leave your observations here : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3869167/830567 .

Comment: No it has not, looks like the elementary knowledge of generalized form can not be determined by finite terms is not a common knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my observations:

$k = 1$
$$\begin{align*} j &= 1 \quad& \{2\cdot1, 1\cdot1\}\quad&\text{descending numbers }\cdot\text{binomial coefficients}\\
j&= 2 \quad& \{1,1\} \quad&\text{binomial coefficients}\\
\end{align*}$$
$k = 2$
$$\begin{align*} j &= 1 \quad& \{6\cdot1, 3\cdot2, 1\cdot1\}\quad&\text{triangular numbers }\cdot\text{binomial coefficients}\\
j &= 2 \quad& \{4\cdot1, 3\cdot2, 2\cdot1\}\quad&\text{descending numbers }\cdot\text{binomial coefficients}\\
j &= 3 \quad& \{1,2,1\} \quad&\text{binomial coefficients}\\
\end{align*}$$
$k = 3$
$$\begin{align*} j&=1 \quad& \{20\cdot1,10\cdot3,4\cdot3,1\cdot1\}\quad&\text{tetrahedral numbers }\cdot\text{binomial coefficients}\\
j &= 2 \quad& \{15\cdot1, 10\cdot3, 6\cdot3, 3\cdot1\}\quad&\text{triangular numbers }\cdot\text{binomial coefficients}\\
j &= 3 \quad& \{6\cdot1, 5\cdot3, 4\cdot3 ,3\cdot1\} \quad&\text{descending numbers }\cdot\text{binomial coefficients}\\
j &= 4 \quad& \{1,3,3,1\} \quad&\text{binomial coefficients}\\
\end{align*}$$

FWIW, tetrahedral numbers are also called triangular pyramidal numbers.

So there seems to be quite a few predictable things increasing here:

- the degree of the binomial expansion
- the shift of the multiplying sequence
- the numerical "dimension" of the multiplying sequence