# Can the pattern of these sequences be revealed?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I have encountered with these sequences while doing some mathematical induction and I am trying to reveal the function. I have these series on $k$,$j$ and $i=(1,2\cdots j) $ as following:

$k=1$ :

$$j=1:\;\{1\}$$

$k=2$ :

$$j=1:\;\{1\},\quad j=2:\;\{4,2\}$$

$k=3$ :

$$j=1:\; \{1\},\quad  
 j=2:\; \{6,3\},\quad j=3:\; \{15,15,3\}$$

$k=4$ :

$$j=1:\; \{1\},\quad  
 j=2:\; \{8,4\},\quad j=3:\; \{28,28,6\},\quad j=4:\; \{56,84,36,4\} $$

$k=5$ :

$$j=1:\; \{1\},\quad  
 j=2:\; \{10,5\},\quad j=3:\; \{45,45,10\},\quad j=4:\; \{120,180,80,10\}\quad j=5:\; \{210,420,280,70,5\}  $$

We can write them down as

$k=1:\quad$  $1$

$k=2:\quad$ $1\;$;$\;4,2$

$k=3:\quad$ $1\;$;$\;6,3\;$;$\;15,15,3$

$k=4:\quad$ $1\;$;$\;8,4\;$;$\;28,28,6\;$;$\;56,84,36,4\;$

$k=5:\quad$$1\;$;$\;10,5\;$;$\;45,45,10\;$;$\;120,180,80,10\:$;$\;210,420,280,70,5\;$

Any observations on these series!

I think these series is connected somehow to these [Can the pattern of these series be revealed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3868687/830567), since they arise from the same problem I am working on.

Comment: Have you tried https://oeis.org/

Comment: @AndyWalls , can you please leave your observations here.

Comment: @LogicalGooGoo Yes. But I couldn't make it out.

Comment: How are these sequences obtained? What is the definition?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are working with expansion of binomials apparently, these numbers, like the ones in your linked question, can be found on [Pascal's Triangle in some manner](https://www.houseofmaths.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Strictly-Come-Counting-Pascals-Triangle-1-600x359.jpg).

I'll use the following notation

$S^0_n$ : Ones sequence

$S^1_n$ : Natural numbers, i.e. $\{1, 2, 3, 4, \dots \}$

$S^2_n$ : Triangular numbers

$S^3_n$ : Tetrahedral numbers

$\dots$

$S^M_n$ : M-Simplex numbers

So your numbers are

$\begin{align*}k &= 1:\quad S^0_1\\
\\
k&=2:\quad S^0_2,\{S^1_4, S^1_2\} \\
\\
k&=3:\quad S^0_3,\{S^1_6, S^1_3\},\{S^2_5, S^2_5, S^2_2\} \\
\\
k&=4:\quad S^0_4,\{S^1_8, S^1_4\},\{S^2_7, S^2_7, S^2_3\}, \{S^3_6, S^3_7?, S^2_8?, S^3_2\} \\
\\
k&=5:\quad S^0_5,\{S^1_{10}, S^1_5\},\{S^2_9, S^2_9, S^2_4\}, \{S^3_8, ???, ???, S^3_3\}, \{S^4_7,??? ,??? , S^4_5? ,S^4_2 \} \\
\end{align*}$

You should have more insight into the "?" entries as you know the steps that are generating these numbers.